# How do I convert this HTML text to an SQLite database?

Tags: java, c++, sqlite

```
<h1>Abasement</h1>
<hw>A*base"ment</hw> <tt>(#)</tt>, 
<tt>n.</tt> 
<ety>[Cf. F. <ets>abaissement</ets>.]</ety> 
<def>The act of abasing, humbling, or bringing low; the state of being abased or humbled;humiliation.</def>
```

I have a file with definitions of words like this, enclosed in tags. I'd like to convert this to an SQLite database with the fields Word, Pronunciation, Part_Of_Speech, Etymology and Definition. Any help is appreciated.

[My first question here!]

Answer (score 2):

You can't just simply 'convert' it (unless there happens to be a tool out there that would do it for you).  You have to create a SQLite database first and create a table for the data.  Maybe name the table 'Words', then create columns for each field, and figure out how to do a SQL INSERT to get your data into it.

Comment: Well, that's not really true, is it? I have since asking the question discovered XML parsing, which can then be used to populate a SQlite database.